Count consecutive elements in Pandas list
I have created the following pandas dataframe:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ds = {'col1':[1,"S",3,4,"S"], 'col2' : [6,"S",8,9,"S"],'col3' : [67,None,87,79,"S"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=ds)

df['col4']= df[['col1','col2','col3']].values.tolist()

The dataframe looks like this:
print(df)

  col1 col2  col3          col4
0    1    6    67    [1, 6, 67]
1    S    S  None  [S, S, None]
2    3    8    87    [3, 8, 87]
3    4    9    79    [4, 9, 79]
4    S    S     S     [S, S, S]

For each record, I need to calculate the number of consecutive "S" inside col4. The resulting dataframe would look like this:
  col1 col2  col3          col4   iCount
0    1    6    67    [1, 6, 67]      0
1    S    S  None  [S, S, None]      2
2    3    8    87    [3, 8, 87]      0
3    4    9    79    [4, 9, 79]      0
4    S    S     S     [S, S, S]      3

I have tried this code:
col4 = np.array(df['col4'])
iCount = 0
for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in range(len(col4[i])):

        if(col4[i][j] == "S"):
            iCount += 1
    
        else:
            iCount = 0

df['iCount'] = iCount

But I get the following dataframe:
  col1 col2  col3          col4  iCount
0    1    6    67    [1, 6, 67]       3
1    S    S  None  [S, S, None]       3
2    3    8    87    [3, 8, 87]       3
3    4    9    79    [4, 9, 79]       3
4    S    S     S     [S, S, S]       3

Please can someone help me find the error?

What should be the output if you have a list like ['S', 'S', None, 'S']? and why?

Mozway, you're always spot on! The results would be 2 (I am looking at the max consecutive). Just seen your answer: that works. Thanks again !

I would use itertools.groupby:
from itertools import groupby

def consec(lst):
    return max((len(list(g)) for k,g in
                groupby(lst, lambda x: x=='S') if k), default=0)

df['iCount'] = df['col4'].map(consec)

NB. using max here to get the longest sequence since there could be more than one stretch of S's, but you could use min/sum or any other logic.
If you are sure there is a maximum of one series of S per list, you could simplify to:
df['iCount'] = [sum(x=='S' for x in lst) for lst in df['col4']]

Output:
  col1 col2  col3          col4  iCount
0    1    6    67    [1, 6, 67]       0
1    S    S  None  [S, S, None]       2
2    3    8    87    [3, 8, 87]       0
3    4    9    79    [4, 9, 79]       0
4    S    S     S     [S, S, S]       3


For max consecutive occurrence of "S" you can try following:
s = df['col4'].explode()=="S"
df['iCount'] = pd.Series(
    np.where(
        s,
        s.groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1,
        0,
    ),
    index = s.index).groupby(level=0).agg(max)

The idea is flatten the lists, calculate max consecutive occurrences and then aggregate them back.
Or this way:
s = df['col4'].explode()=="S"
df['iCount'] = (s.groupby((s!=s.shift()).cumsum()).transform('size')*s).groupby(level=0).agg(max)

For just count number of S in the lists you can try this:
df['iCount'] = df['col4'].apply(pd.Series.value_counts)['S'].fillna(0)

The idea here is to use value_counts function per row for the specified column, filter by required string, in your case it is 'S', and fill 0s for no occurrence rows.

Quick note: 1- converting to Series is quite expensive here (better use collections.Counter), 2- given OP's clarification, that wouldn't work since counting the successive S is desired (not the total). ['S', 'S', None, 'S'] should return 2.

Thanks @mozway, I've edited based on your comment, totally missed the successive part. Regarding your first comment, I'm a little bit confused. I'm not converting to Series, but rather using value_counts function. Behind the scenes it creates another DataFrame, which agree, may be quite expensive. So df['col4'].apply(pd.Series.value_counts) calculates each unique value occurrence.

Just use the column values.
iCount_list = []
for row in df['col4']:
    count = 0
    consecutive_s = 0
    for value in row:
        if value == "S":
            consecutive_s += 1
            count = max(count, consecutive_s)
        else:
            consecutive_s = 0
    iCount_list.append(count)

df['iCount'] = iCount_list

It will give :
col1 col2  col3          col4  iCount
0    1    6    67    [1, 6, 67]       0
1    S    S  None  [S, S, None]       2
2    3    8    87    [3, 8, 87]       0
3    4    9    79    [4, 9, 79]       0
4    S    S     S     [S, S, S]       3


count=0
list1=[]
for i in df["col4"]:
    for j in i:
        if j=="S":
            count +=1
    print(count)
    list1.append(count)
    count=0
df['count']=list1

we can not directly iterate through the columns first you need to select the column you want to iterate through then using that you can iterate through the list in that column and check if that list contains the object you are searching.

Welcome to SO! Please validate your response with output obtained using provided input.

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['1', 'S', '3', '4', 'S'],
    'col2': ['6', 'S', '8', '9', 'S'],
    'col3': ['67', None, '87', '79', 'S'],
    'col4': [[1, 6, 67], ['S', 'S', None], [3, 8, 87], [4, 9, 79], ['S', 'S', 'S']]
})

df['S_count'] = df['col4'].apply(lambda col : pd.Series(col).eq('S').cumsum()
                                 .mul(pd.Series(col).eq('S'))
                                 .max() )
                                                            
print(df)     
'''
 col1 col2  col3          col4  S_count
0    1    6    67    [1, 6, 67]        0
1    S    S  None  [S, S, None]        2
2    3    8    87    [3, 8, 87]        0
3    4    9    79    [4, 9, 79]        0
4    S    S     S     [S, S, S]        3
'''                                                       


One liner approach!
df['iCount'] = df['col4'].apply(lambda x: (series:=pd.Series(x)).groupby(series.ne(series.shift()).cumsum().iloc[series[series=="S"].index]).cumcount().max() + 1).fillna(0)

As a function:
def func(x):
    series = pd.Series(x)
    groups = series.ne(series.shift()).cumsum().iloc[series[series == "S"].index]
    out = series.groupby(groups).cumcount().max() + 1
    return out
                                                     
df['iCount'] = df['col4'].apply(func).fillna(0)

Output:
   col1 col2 col3          col4  iCount
0     1    6   67    [1, 6, 67]     0.0
1  None    S    S  [None, S, S]     2.0
2     3    8   87    [3, 8, 87]     0.0
3     4    9   79    [4, 9, 79]     0.0
4     S    S    S     [S, S, S]     3.0

Use pd.Series.groupby, and filter items that are equals to "S", then get those indexes to filter the groups for cumsum and cumcount.

IMO using pandas makes no sense here, that makes the code ~1000 times slower than using pure python.
